# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' (Binance)

Tags: python-3.x, binance

I expect this simple script that connects to Binance and gets the details of my account to work using [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) library (version: 0.7.9) out of the box but it does not seem to. I am able to connect to the API and get the price of bitcoin therefore I am confident the error is not this.

```py
import os

from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from twisted.internet import reactor

# Get keys
api_key = os.environ.get('binance_api')
api_secret = os.environ.get('binance_secret')

# Connect to Binance
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
print(client.get_account())
```

gives the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9c56ae96674c> in <module>
----> 1 print(client.get_account())

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py in get_account(self, **params)
   1765 
   1766         """
-> 1767         return self._get('account', True, data=params)
   1768 
   1769     def get_asset_balance(self, asset, **params):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py in _get(self, path, signed, version, **kwargs)
    235 
    236     def _get(self, path, signed=False, version=PUBLIC_API_VERSION, **kwargs):
--> 237         return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
    238 
    239     def _post(self, path, signed=False, version=PUBLIC_API_VERSION, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py in _request_api(self, method, path, signed, version, **kwargs)
    200         uri = self._create_api_uri(path, signed, version)
    201 
--> 202         return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
    203 
    204     def _request_withdraw_api(self, method, path, signed=False, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py in _request(self, method, uri, signed, force_params, **kwargs)
    178             # generate signature
    179             kwargs['data']['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
--> 180             kwargs['data']['signature'] = self._generate_signature(kwargs['data'])
    181 
    182         # sort get and post params to match signature order

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py in _generate_signature(self, data)
    133         ordered_data = self._order_params(data)
    134         query_string = '&'.join(["{}={}".format(d[0], d[1]) for d in ordered_data])
--> 135         m = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
    136         return m.hexdigest()
    137 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Checking the [docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#account-information-user_data), I don't see what I might be doing wrong. Since the debug logs indicate the error might be in the binance api but I'm not sure because this is a basic feature and should work without any trouble.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys were not imported correctly, check with `'binance_api' in os.environ`. Add `set -gx ENV_NAME=value` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`