# Why do i get this error with the python binance library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance, binance-api-client

When i run my code i get this error. If i search for this error i only get results where the file was called binance.py, which gives an error, but i named my file bin_bot.py

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin_bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance'
```

My code:

```
import os

from binance.client import Client

api_key = os.environ.get("My API")
api_secret = os.environ.get("My Secret")

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

print(client.futures_account_balance())
```

I am grateful for any answer.

error2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin_bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(client.futures_account_balance())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/binance/client.py", line 5361, in futures_account_balance
    return self._request_futures_api('get', 'balance', True, data=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/binance/client.py", line 333, in _request_futures_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/binance/client.py", line 306, in _request
    kwargs = self._get_request_kwargs(method, signed, force_params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/binance/client.py", line 262, in _get_request_kwargs
    kwargs['data']['signature'] = self._generate_signature(kwargs['data'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/binance/client.py", line 221, in _generate_signature
    m = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Try from this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106239/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-encode-binance)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have both **python2** and **python3** on your system.

PIP has installed `python-binance` for **python2** and script runs with **python3**
Try:

```
python3 -m pip install python-binance
```

Comment: i did install the python-binance library with sudo pip3 install python-binance, but i tried your command aswell but i still get the same error. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: you are making sure that take your script running with **python3** too, e.g. `python3 file_name.py`

Comment: i run the file with sudo python3 bin_bot.py

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install python-binance
```

and then I was having luck when I removed .client after binance.

```
import os

from binance import Client

api_key = os.environ.get("My API")
api_secret = os.environ.get("My Secret")

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

print(client.futures_account_balance())
```

Documentation
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In the documentation, they just call bianance, not binance.client.

Comment: Ive tried your code, but when i run it i get an other error (error2 on question).

Comment: What is the correct API key that you should be using for this? Are you sure you are using the correct one? Looking at other posts, it appears that your keys aren't being imported correctly. Maybe look into this. https://accounts.binance.com/en/login?return_to=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmluYW5jZS5jb20vZW4vbXkvc2V0dGluZ3MvYXBpLW1hbmFnZW1lbnQ=

Comment: I think im using the correct api key and api secret. I just created them like 30mins ago and the api has rights to futures.

Comment: Look at this post, seems like this user had a similar error to yours. I can't look at it myself since I currently don't have a Binance API key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106239/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-encode-binance

Comment: Oh ive found the fault. The template i was using imports the API with the os environ library for saftey if you share your script. I remove the os.environ.get and replaced it with the API directly and it works fine now. Thanks for you help